# Pyttsx: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, attributeerror, pyttsx

Hi to everyone and thanks in advance

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Hello World')
engine.runAndWait()
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\eclipse\workspace\Ai_Project\AI\Ai_Brain.py", line 8, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I am on Windows 7 using Python 2.7 and eclipse neon. Is this some kind of compatibility issue? I have searched a lot of related questions but applying the answers on my case didn't fix the error

Comment: Do you have a pyttsx.py in your work dir?

Comment: By that you mean in my workspace folder? No there i have 2 files _init_.py and AI_Brain.py. If you mean whether i installed pyttsx in my python installation , it is a yes.

Answer (score 0):

After importing the `pyttsx` module:

```
import pyttsx
```

use the command

```
dir(pyttsx)
```

Your output would be something as

```
['Engine',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '_activeEngines',
 'driver',
 'drivers',
 'engine',
 'init',
 'weakref']
```

(see `'init'` in it near the end).

I guess your output will be *different* - it will reveal *which* module you actually imported regardless of its name `pyttsx`.

Comment: Where should i use the command? In the eclipse code? If yes it didn't show me anything(just blank).

Comment: There are 2 possibilities, I meant the first: **1)** In the *PyDev console* - probably right bottom part of your Eclipse IDE with "Console" tab. From the last icon (with a tooltip Open Console) choose "PyDev Console). **2)** In the *Eclipse editor*, as you did, but then you have to use `print` command: `print dir(pyttsx)`

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy i guess and i post the answer in case someone in future has the same problem and every query he/she made didn't work. Consider this a human error and check your compatibility issues. In my case problem was that instead of pywin32-py2.7.exe i installed pywin32-219.win-**amd64**-py2.7.

Thanks to everyone who read or answered my question