# AttributeError: module 'pyttsx3' has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx

First of all, I'm using:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.2 (but I've tried with Python 3.5.4 too)
- [pyttsx3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx3/2.6) module

I'm trying to use pyttsx3 but I just can't initialize it, with the official code examples.

My code (just like the examples from [here](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#speaking-text) and [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx3/2.6)):

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Just a sample text.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

And the second line gives me this error:

> AttributeError: module 'pyttsx3' has no attribute 'init'

I installed it with PIP:

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

And I tried to fix it installing pypiwin32 but it still doesn't work:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

When I execute the following script:

```
import pyttsx3
print(dir(pyttsx3))
```

I get this:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'pyttsx3']
```

There is this:

```
drivers (folder)
__pycache__ (folder)
driver.py
engine.py
six.py
voice.py
__init__.py
```

At:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3
```

And the contents of the file `__init__.py` (I omitted comments):

```
from .engine import Engine
import weakref

_activeEngines = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

def init(driverName=None, debug=False):
    try:
        eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
    except KeyError:
        eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
        _activeEngines[driverName] = eng
    return eng
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the module pyttsx3 is not properly initialised. I hope you don't have a file named **pyttsx3.py** anywhere in the module path.  I found a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912378/pyttsx-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-init).

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot that I created a "pyttsx3.py" file for testing and I didn't remove nor rename it. Thanks a lot!